# Installing Ubuntu from USB stick (having Ubuntu already installed)

Tags: usb, disk, reinstall

I've got Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit installed on my computer. I would like to re-do the installation.

I've created a bootable USB in a different (non-Ubuntu) computer. I try to it plug in: nothing happens.

I restart the computer: still nothing happens, Ubuntu starts just as normal.

How can I make the computer open from the USB disk in order to start the installation?

Comment: What's the exact reason you want to "redo the installation"?

Comment: See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/) to another question at AskUbuntu and the answers to that question. It shows a lot of possible reasons why there can be problems to boot and install from a USB drive. -- In order to get more specific advice, you must tell us more about your computer and how it is set up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Depending on the make of the computer, you can choose the boot disk by selecting F2, F9, F10, F12, etc, at the time of boot. or you can choose the USB as first HDD in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

To boot from the USB stick you usually have to go into your BIOS or boot order.

Do this by pressing one of the F keys (<kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, etc.) right when your computer starts (shutdown your computer first). From there you can select to boot from USB.

Also make sure you actually formated your USB to be bootable (with "Startup Disk Creator" on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

use the disk image creater or writer on ubuntu os's to make your usb this is what i do all the time. never fails for me.

make sure you check the box saying disk image and find folder and download  which ever os your using to usb, find program that says disks to check to see if the usb is boot-able if not boot-able re-download from internet.

if not use rufus for windows

if all fails search online for usb boot loaders. if this helps your welcome. i have most ubuntu flavors myself on one computer. good luck to you.

Don't change my message  mint/peppermimt editions at's called the usb/disk image creater or writer are called on these two os's. so don't change my messages i run all ubuntu os's plus the all flavour's.if you don't believe me download all editions yourself of ubuntu's. only been modding my pc's and laptop's since I was 12 now 30.

Comment: Please clarify the second paragraph.  What are you supposed to download to the USB? What are you supposed to re-download? Please add more details to the third paragraph, because right now it's vague and not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had made the USB bootable using Rufus or LiveUSB Creator. If so, your USB is bootable.

Your USB is not booting when you are restarting the computer because the USB drive will be below your hard drive in the boot order. So your, hard drive actually gets booted first and you are not able to boot from USB.

So when your computer is getting on, actually on the first boot screen, press (<kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>,...). One of these keys will land you in the boot menu page and select your USB drive using arrow keys and then press enter.

You could change the boot order permanently by pressing the key required for landing you to the BIOS options. It might be <kbd>F2</kbd>.

For getting the key regarding boot menu, you could search your hardware (Motherboard) page on the web.